# How do I insert a Font Awesome glyph/icon in a CakePHP submit button?

Tags: cakephp, font-awesome

I am trying to insert a [Font Awesome icon](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) in a submit button using CakePHP and Twitter Bootstrap 3.

Here is the code:

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Send', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning fa fa-envelope', 'escape' => false));
```

It works for regular buttons, but for the input that which is generated by the FormHelper above, it does not render with an icon. Can I tweak FormHelper::submit to solve this?

I could use other types of FormHelper buttons, but the CakePHP docs explicitly states that:

> Try to avoid using FormHelper::input() to generate submit buttons. Use FormHelper::submit() instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use:

```
echo $this->Form->button('<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send', array(
    'type' => 'button',
    'class' => 'btn btn-warning fa fa-envelope',
    'escape' => false
));
```

I don't think the quote you listed is to keep you from doing this, but it should probably be clarified.

Bottom line, if it generates the correct HTML, then it's fine.  But - to it's point, using `button` or `submit` instead of `input (so it doesn't have a value that's submitted) is the way to go.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::button

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and the glyph shows up but the Bootstrap font style is removed so it looks wonky. But I agree with your statement that ->button should be fine by principle!
Edit: the .fa  style "font-family: FontAwesome;" is the culprit.

Comment: Ah, the solution: echo $this->Form->button('<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning', 'escape' => false)); - this does not muck up the font by changing the class. But this solution did not work with FormHelper::submit, only with ::button. Thanks for getting me on the right track!

Comment: Cool - glad to help.  Thanks for the update.  Have updated my answer to match to help future users.